# Nestes razor views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, razor

I have a view, which has its own controller and it includes libraries such as: bootstrap, jquery etc. Its path is "Views/MyView".

Now I have another view: "Views/MainView", which also includes the same libraries.

Can I include 'MyView' inside this view since it is not in Shared folder? Frameworks will be loaded twice I guess?

But this is the only way that the view will have everywhere all needed libraries.

Comment: What do you mean by "inside this view since it is not in Shared folder?"? Yes, I think script and css will be loaded twice.

Comment: You can use `@{ Html.RenderAction("ViewName", "Controller");}` to load a view within a view

Comment: Thank you, I didn't think of that.Why then have partial view at all if you can   have nesting like this?